# token Mismatch Exception on localhost

Tags: php, laravel

i got error "token mismatch exception" only on local machine, on production server is ok.
In head index file i put this:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
```

and under form open tag:

```
{!!csrf_field()!!}
```

Comment: What is the URL that you hit ? is it for all the forms that you have ?

Comment: I tried {{csrf_field()}}, no success...

Comment: in your controller where index page is redirect .... Add this `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php`

Comment: For form submit is using angular, maybe here is problem, then why on production server it's ok?

Comment: Why do u make it in meta tag?

Comment: try to clear cache : `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 1):

you can comment the line  \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class, token in kernel.php or either check your routes list is coming using PHP this command

artisan route:list

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate new api key on your localhost:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Cheers!

Comment: Why do u make it in meta tag? Maybe solution is here:https://laravel.io/forum/01-30-2015-laravel5-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken.

Comment: where i should put this? Here :https://laravel.io/forum/01-30-2015-laravel5-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken also in meta is csrf-token are.

Comment: This is a link to forum where this problem is tried to be resolved.